# I get tons of these in my errorlog 'The controller for path X was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im a bit confused of why I keep getting these error messages in my error log:

```
The controller for path '/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

and

```
The controller for path '/css/bootstrap.css.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

I get about 4 hits every minute so its filling up my error log pretty fast.

Comment: This is something to do with your routing. For some reason, it's trying to route your calls to the CSS and fonts folders to an MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `woff` files that I noticed on the browser end returning 404, and you simply need to identify these files as static content in your `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="map" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```